# How to undo Git - All conflicts fixed but you are still merging

Tags: git, merge, rollback

I made Git pull which caused little complicated merge. I could not handle the merge so I try to rollback the code. It worked BUT git is still merging. I need to get to the state where I was before merge which is still not commited. I know how to reset HEAD but this is not commited it is still merging.
Can somebody tell me how to do it?

Comment: use `git merge --abort`

Comment: Make an answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git merge --abort` or `git reset --merge`.